# md-datepicker width is too big

Tags: angular-material

I'm stuck to customize size of md-datepicker! I use it in md-input-container but the size after the picker is shown up ,it takes all my screen size.Below is my code:

```
<md-input-container flex-xs>
    <label>Start Date</label>
    <md-datepicker ng-model="leave.start_date"></md-datepicker>
</md-input-container>
```

Do I need to include any original styles of this datepicker? Thank in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use the function for manipulate width and hide image of calendar as:

```
var app = angular.module('StarterApp', ['ngMaterial']);

app.controller('AppController', function($scope) {
    $scope.initDatepicker = function(){
        angular.element(".md-datepicker-button").each(function(){
            var el = this;
            var ip = angular.element(el).parent().find("input").bind('click', function(e){
                angular.element(el).click();
            });
            angular.element(this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
        });
    };
});
```

**CSS**
This comes from how the date picker is build behind the scene

```
.inputdemoBasicUsage .md-datepicker-button {
  width: 36px;
}
.inputdemoBasicUsage .md-datepicker-input-container {
  margin-left: 2px;
}
.md-datepicker-input-container {
  display: block;
}
.md-datepicker-input[placeholder] {
  color:red;
}
.padding-top-0 {
  padding-top: 0px;
}
.padding-bottom-0 {
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="StarterApp" ng-controller="AppController" ng-init="initDatepicker();">
    <md-content flex class="padding-top-0 padding-bottom-0" layout="row">
        <md-datepicker ng-model="user.submissionDate1" md-placeholder="Start date" flex ng-click="ctrl.openCalendarPane($event)"></md-datepicker>
        <md-datepicker ng-model="user.submissionDate2" md-placeholder="Due date" flex></md-datepicker>
    </md-content>
</div>
```